# Url generate Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have url format `/catalog/{countryName}/`. Need fill in the url

```
$country = 'russia'
(\route('country',['countryName' => $country])); // http://localhost/catalog/russia
```

Result = `http://localhost/catalog/russia`.

But I need result = `/catalog/russia` formaty only path use standard method Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your route like this:

```
route('pages.countryCatalog', $country)
```

In your route, try putting {country}.

For example:

```
Route::get('/catalog/{country?}', 'Your Controller Name here@Your Method')->name('pages.countryCatalog');
```

Name the page what you want, just make sure they match so the route knows which route to go to!

Note: you don't need the question mark in the { }, its saying its an optional parameter.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, but not understand me bro)) Result  - `http://localhost/catalog/russia`, i need only path `/catalog/russia`